# Remove seconds of silence at end of GarageBand exports

Tags: music, mp3, ilife, garageband

Whenever I export a song to disk from GarageBand, it automatically adds a few seconds of silence to the end.

I don't want that silence, as the files I'm exporting are sound effect mixes to be played manually one at a time. I know that I can go into Audacity and manually remove all of the silence at the end, but I'd rather avoid spending that much time cleaning up after GarageBand.

**Is there a way to tell GarageBand not to add silence to the end of tracks it exports?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, GarageBand doesn't add anything to the end of exported tracks, *but* it exports as much as there's sound in any track. Therefore, to avoid having extra "stuff" exported, you should always create a loop region and export with that. As you can see in the following picture, I'm at second 47 in the "timeline", however, I've created a region (the yellow bar on top) that starts at second 1 instead of 0, therefore creating a 46 second clip.

The exported version can be seen in quicktime with a length of 46 seconds, without any extra silence or sound.

[image: GarageBand Shot]

In order to create such region, you have to activate the "repeat/loop" (next to the Play button in GarageBand). That will create an extra space below the Beat Bar (where you move the Play Head). When you hover your mouse over that small region, the cursor changes. You can click and "drag" to paint the yellow zone. That's the zone that will be repeated over and over.

Always export with a repeat/loop zone created and Garageband will **only** export that.

**NOTE:** Logic Pro/Express behaves the same way when creating bounces.

There's a draggable cursor at the end of the timeline on the upper right corner. If it is beyond the end of your sound on your longest track GB will include that much silence. Drag it back to the end of your longest track, or leave however many seconds of silence you want.

#### Update 2020 - What about iOS?

I don't use macOS anymore but if you want to do this on iOS or iPadOS, if I don't incorrectly recall, your only choice is to have a region that encompasses the part you want to export, tap it (to select it), then tap it again (to see a floating set of buttons), and pick "Loop". I don't know/think there's a way to do the same "playback region selector" on iOS. I may be wrong, but this question was about the OS X version of GarageBand so I don't know more :)

Comment: I followed your instructions and it worked, thanks :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you too ;)

Comment: The "draggable cursor" at the upper right of the timeline's end is hidden behind the horizontal zoom control.  Great UI from Apple.

Comment: I don’t see the tools mentioned in my iPhone or iPad versions of GarageBand (app) nor can I figure out how to run with the concept. I did try adding blank tracks, clip tool, exact number of measures, trimming and so on. Hope there is an app specific method!

Comment: @OldUncleHo I updated the answer to include _what I know_ about iOS/GarageBand but like I mentioned in the updated version, I no longer use Apple computers so... can't help you there. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

In further detail, in order to see the cursor change, start at the beginning of the track. 
In Garageband 11, the loop region icon is located next to the metronome.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:

Also the "Include Audio Tail" switch on the bounce page in LPX determines whether the long tails of reverbs are added at the end of the file.